# Fullcalendar jquery, not show special characters (ę, ą, ń..)

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, character, fullcalendar

I have problem with fullcalendar, because not show special characters (ę,ą,ń) in button prev, next, title and events.. This is implement in zend views phtml. Everywhere special characters are (menu, news, etc..). I have set charset utf-8.. Why this not works? I use lang package - polish to fullcalendar. Help me please!

View script:

```
<?php $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/fullcalendar-2.1.1/fullcalendar.css'); ?>
<?php $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/fullcalendar-2.1.1/fullcalendar.print.css', 'print'); ?>
<?php $this->headScript()->appendFile('/fullcalendar-2.1.1/lib/moment.min.js'); ?>
<?php $this->headScript()->appendFile('/fullcalendar-2.1.1/fullcalendar.min.js'); ?>
<?php $this->headScript()->appendFile('/js/lang.all.js'); ?>

<?php $this->headScript()->captureStart(); ?>
                var calendar_elements = [
                    <?php foreach($this->events as $event): ?>
                        {
                        title: '"<?php echo str_replace('\'','\\\'',$event['name']); ?>"',
                            start: '<?php echo $event['date']; ?>',
                            editable: false,

                        },
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    ];
            <?php $this->headScript()->captureEnd(); ?>
                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12"><div id='calendar'></div></div>
                    </div>


<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
                        lang: 'pl',
            editable: true,
                        eventBackgroundColor: 'red',
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: calendar_elements,
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Where have you set the charset?

Comment: i have set characters in application.ini. I tried in layout as meta, not worked too..

Comment: @programmer2014: is your project in utf-8? You could try to check polish translation in /js/lang.all.js and see if special chars don't be displayed also there (in an editor with utf-8 set)

Comment: yes, i see correctly special characters in lang-all.js in NetBeans.. where is problem? :(

Comment: @programmer2014: the file/project encoding is utf-8?

Comment: yes, i have set encoding utf8 in application.ini and layout.phtml, which is loading to this view.. i haven't more ideas.. why i can see special characters everywhere, but no in fullcalendar plugin?

Comment: i forgot tell you my events in this calendar display correctly special characters.. only buttons and title are bad..

Answer (score 4):

İ understand you very well. Actually, this is the problem of Full Calendar that it does not render the code as html. Using event render function we can solve this problem.

```
    eventRender: function(event,element){
        element.find('.fc-title').html(event.title);
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Set meta tag in yout template.

```
<meta charset='utf-8' />
```

Answer (score 0):

for later versions of fullcalendar

```
eventRender: function(info){
      $(info.el).find('.fc-title').html(info.event.title);
},
```